# Getting error resource not found with AREA in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: `/Service_engineer/Service_Engineer/Service_Engineer_Index`

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4075.0
**

this is my .cs file in area

```
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace support3_1_20.Areas.Service_engineer
    {
        public class Service_engineerAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
        {
            public override string AreaName 
            {
                get 
                {
                    return "Service_engineer";
                }
            }

            public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
            {
                context.MapRoute(
                    "Service_engineer_default",
                    "Service_engineer/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my controller in area

```
      using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace YourDefaultNamesace.support3_1_20.Areas.Service_engineer.Controllers
    {
        public class Service_EngineerController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Service_engineer/Service_Engineer
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
    }
```

this is my view

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Service_Engineer_Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Service_Engineer_Index</h2>
```

this is my layout

````
   div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
               </div>
               <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                       <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Eng_Index","Service_Engineer_Index","Service_Engineer", new { area ="Service_engineer" }, null)</li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
      ```    

what is the problem. after i click on a link i get an error...
i also check below code too
````

````
    protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }    
```
````

Comment: How about just Request `/Service_engineer/Service_Engineer` url?

Comment: does not work tried that also, do you find any error through out

Comment: Clean the solution by right click on your Project > Clean, and then Rebuild it.  Perhaps the assembly is not properly generated and browser is not able to render it properly.